# Logic bricks in BGE OR similar function for animation in blender render

Tags: rendering, animation, game-engine

I am using Logic bricks in BGE to move a sun across the sky, I want to use the logic brick function OR similar function to do the same in the blender render for an animation, what would you suggest?

Comment: Logic bricks are BGE only. Blender will not care the Logic bricks (it just provides the editor). Moving in Blender is pretty simple: just play an animation (action).

Comment: Do you want to play an animation or have continuous motion?